# Timestamp.valueOf() returns different value according to JVM version

Tags: java, datetime

```
Timestamp sTs = Timestamp.valueOf("1900-12-31 23:59:59.999"); // Make Timestamp
System.out.println("sTs====>" + sTs.getTime());

sTs====> -2177485200001  // in jdk 1.4


Timestamp sTs = Timestamp.valueOf("1900-12-31 23:59:59.999"); // Make Timestamp
System.out.println("sTs====>" + sTs.getTime());

sTs====> -2177483400001  // in jdk 1.5
```

Why are the two values different?

Comment: Jon Skeet will know this one :)

Comment: Maybe he is framing the answer by this time.

Comment: @MartijnCourteaux Jon Skeet only knows basic programming and simple OOP concepts ^_^

Comment: JDK 1.6 ===> -2177452800001

Comment: The weird thing is that the difference is only half an hour. According to wiki, only a very few places use 30 minute shifts in DTS.

Comment: `Timestamp.valueOf` uses the local timezone of the computer (because it uses the deprecated 6-argument constructor of superclass `java.util.Date`) - unless we know the timezone of the OP it's hard to answer conclusively.

Comment: My guess is that the OP is in India, the biggest country I believe that has a 30 minute-multiple timezone offset from GMT (since we see a 30-minute difference). It probably has to do with historical changes in timezone offset, India Standard Time was only introduced in 1906 so the date above is from before its introduction.

Answer (score 12):

According to a now deleted post on the Sun website

> Daylight Saving Time (DST) is a system of handling the changing
>   amounts of daylight throughout the year. The goal of DST is to
>   maximize the daylight hours available during typical waking hours. By
>   adjusting clocks ahead a standard amount, usually an hour, people can
>   have more daylight available during their typical work day. For
>   example, suppose you wake daily at 7:00 AM. In the spring, the sun
>   rises earlier each day. Instead of waking up at 6:00 AM to take
>   advantage of the daylight, DST observers move their clocks ahead an
>   hour. The effect is that they can continue to wake at 7:00 AM
>   according to the clock and enjoy more daylight. In the fall, people
>   set their clocks back an hour as sunrise happens later each day.
>
> The United States has planned a change to its DST observance beginning
>   in 2007. The Energy Policy Act of 2005 mandates that DST will start on
>   the second Sunday in March and end on the first Sunday in November. In
>   2007, the start and stop dates will be March 11 and November 4,
>   respectively. These dates are different from previous DST start and
>   stop dates. In 2006, the dates were the first Sunday in April (April
>   2, 2006) and the last Sunday in October (October 29, 2006).
>
> The Java Runtime Environment (JRE) stores rules about DST observance
>   all around the globe. Older JREs will have outdated rules that will be
>   superseded by the Energy Policy Act of 2005. As a result, applications
>   running on an older JRE may report incorrect time from March 11, 2007
>   through April 2, 2007 and from October 29, 2007 through November 4,
>   200

The change was updated in Java 1.4.2_13. So if your version is older then that you'll see different behaviour.

Comment: @GokulNath Because it's essentially a link only answer. If that link breaks the answer is useless.

Comment: common @JoelWitteveen. Im waiting for an edit before I upvote

Comment: @JoelWitteveen If you only quote the answer with a little explanation, you'll get my +1.

Comment: I'm not sure this is correct. 1900-12-31 would never have been DST, regardless of the JVM version. So there would be no discrepancy.

Answer (score 10):

I think this is because 1.4 probably does not support timezone historical changes (http://www.timezoneconverter.com/tzchist.html). The problem is that Timestamp parses time in local timezone and timezone in your locale was different in 1900 which 1.4 did not take into account but 1.5 did